# Nice formatting of numbers inside Messages

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

When printing string with `StyleBox` by default we get nicely formatted numbers inside string:

```
StyleBox["some text 1000000"] // DisplayForm
```

I mean that the numbers look as if would have additional little spaces: "1 000 000".

But in `Message`s all numbers are displayed without formatting:

```
f::NoMoreMemory = 
  "There are less than `1` bytes of free physical memory (`2` bytes \
is free). $Failed is returned.";
Message[f::NoMoreMemory, 1000000, 98000000]
```

Is there a way to get numbers inside `Message`s to be formatted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use Style to apply the AutoNumberFormatting option:

You can use it to target specific messages:

```
f::NoMoreMemory = 
 "There are less than `1` bytes of free physical memory (`2` bytes is free). $Failed is returned.";

Message[f::NoMoreMemory, 
 Style[1000000, AutoNumberFormatting -> True], 
 Style[98000000, AutoNumberFormatting -> True]]
```

or you can use it with $MessagePrePrint to apply it to all the messages:

```
$MessagePrePrint = Style[#, AutoNumberFormatting -> True] &;

Message[f::NoMoreMemory, 1000000, 98000000]
```

Comment: +1 your method, but using `StyleForm` in place of `Style`, does what Alexey asked for.

Comment: @Brett Champion Is there a way to do this by modifying `Message`'s `Style`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard On my system (*Mathematica* 7.01 for Windows) `Style` and `StyleForm` do the same in this case. What version of *Mathematica* do you use?

Comment: @Alexey Same setup here.  Try to copy and paste `1000000` and then put `+ 5` next to that, and evaluate.  For me, with `Style` I get `5 + 1000000` but with `StyleForm` I get `1000005`

Comment: @Alexey I think there should be a way to do this via a stylesheet, but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The same behavior may be achieved with `Style`: `Style[1000000, AutoNumberFormatting -> True, StripOnInput -> True]`.

Comment: @Alexey is there a reason to prefer that to `StyleForm`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No reasons. I just pointed out the source of the difference: `Style` by default sets `StripOnInput` to `False`.

Comment: @Alexey thanks, it's always good to see a different approach.

Answer (score 5):

I think you want `$MessagePrePrint`

```
$MessagePrePrint = 
   NumberForm[#, DigitBlock -> 3, NumberSeparator -> " "] &;
```

Or, incorporating Sjoerd's suggestion:

```
With[
  {opts =
    AbsoluteOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],
     {DigitBlock, NumberSeparator}]},
  $MessagePrePrint = NumberForm[#, Sequence @@ opts] &];
```

Adapting Brett Champion's method, I believe this allows for copy & paste as you requested:

```
$MessagePrePrint = StyleForm[#, AutoNumberFormatting -> True] &;
```

Comment: It is better to use `NumberSeparator -> "\[ThinSpace]"` with your code. However I'd like do not use any additional characters inside numbers. With `StyleBox["1000000"] // DisplayForm` we get copyable number with nice appearance. I would like to get this inside `Message`s.

Comment: It would be most useful if you get the formatting options from the evaluating notebook, to get things more uniform. So instead of the options above you could use `AbsoluteOptions[
 EvaluationNotebook[], {DigitBlock, DigitBlockMinimum, NumberPoint, 
  NumberSeparator, NumberMultiplier}]`

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries How exactly I should use your code with the example inside the question? I mean `Message[f::NoMoreMemory, 1000000, 98000000]`. Post the answer as separate if it works.

Comment: @Alexey It is interesting the questions and uses that people come up with.  I never try to copy and paste from messages.  I will have to see if I can find a solution for that.  Would storing the numbers elsewhere for reference, rather than copy and paste be of any use?

Comment: @Alexey Popkov Mr. Wizard already did this. The key is the use of Sequence to get rid of the List construction returned by AbsoluteOptions.

Comment: @Alexey see the new version based on Brett's method.